# Scroll does not work in small resolutions

Tags: html, css, scroll

When using lower resolutions than 1024x768 browser scroll not working right. If you notice, when the resolution is smaller I can not see all the purple stripe.

I noticed that the body is at the top, which is weird because the entire page should be inside the body. I do not know if that influences anything.

Url: [www.amsdarquitetura.com.br](http://www.amsdarquitetura.com.br)

Answer (score 2):

It's the negative margins you're setting on div#global. When the viewport is small enough, the negative margins are essentially hiding parts of your page.

Comment: Yes, but how to solve? This manendo he aligned horizontally and vertically.

Comment: To align something horizontally set the width then set the margin: 0 auto; for the same element. Vertically, I'm not sure what you mean - just put a top margin on it if you want it a certain distance from the top of the viewport.

Comment: On load and on resize, check the viewport height, and if it's less than the desired height of the wrapper, add a class that overrides the styles to be top: 0 and margin-top: 0. On resize, if the page gets tall enough, remove that class.

Answer (score 1):

Change #global CSS to:

```
#global {
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I need it to be aligned to the center of the screen. Both horizontally and vertically. Thus it is aligned just vertical.

Comment: Same result. He is aligned vertically only

Comment: If you don't find a solution with css, jquery can do it :

`var A = $(window).height();

var B = $('#global').height();

if(A > B){
     
var C =  (A - B)/2;
     
    $('#global').css('margin-top', C + 'px')
}` + the css as above.